# 直交回帰直線から残差平方和を求める方法

Tags: r

直交回帰直線から残差平方和を求めたいです。
deviance(lm( d[,1] ~ d[,2] ))で線形回帰の残差平方和は求められるようなのですが、直交回帰の場合はどのように求めればよいでしょうか？

直交回帰直線は以下のように求めました。

```
r <- prcomp( ~ d[,1] + d[,2] )
slope <- r$rotation[2,1]/r$rotation[1,1]
intercept <- r$center[2] - slope * r$center[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages('deming')
library(deming)


fit <- deming(d[,1] ~ d[,2])
fit$residuals
```